# Unable to bind v-model with vue-date-picker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have used **vue-date-picker** and **v-model** for two way data binding. Initially I have set value to date(i.e. **startDate** in this case) and in console I am printing that passed value(i.e. **startDate**). At first, that passed value to startDate (i.e. **2019-09-17** is printed) but when I chose new Date, startDate value didn't get updated rather value remained same as it was when it was initially passed.

```
       <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="startDate" class>Start Date</label>
            <datepicker v-model="startDate" :readonly="true" format="YYYY-MM-DD" name="startDate"> 
            </datepicker>
       </div>
       <p>Start Date: {{startDate}}</p>

       <div class="col-md-2">
         <div class="md-form mb-0">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="showDateValues">Apply</button>
         </div>
       </div>
```

> import datepicker from "vue-date-picker";

```
<script>
import datepicker from "vue-date-picker";

export default {
  name: "Example",
  components: {
    datepicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      startDate: "2019-09-17"
    };
  },
  methods:{
    showDateValues(){
      console.log("Start Date: "+this.startDate)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/8788/vue-date-picker/issues/23

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 data() {
    return {
      startDate: new Date("2019-09-17")
    };
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var elm = new Vue({
  el: '.app8',
  mounted () {
    var vm = this
    $('#datedate').datepicker ({
        onSelect: function(dateText) { 
            vm.date = dateText
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col">
      <div class="app8">
          <input v-model="date" name="date" class="input" type="date"  id="datedate">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help